# Unable to install Gatsby on Ubuntu 20

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, gatsby

I am going to deploy the website developed by Gatsby.js on the Ubuntu server.
I installed node and git successfully on Ubuntu 20 server and I was going to install the `gatsby-cli` but I failed with these errors.

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Please feel free to let me know how can I solve this problem.

> ```
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! core-js@2.6.11 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.11 postinstall script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-26T12_39_42_916Z-debug.log
> ```